# How to get text value of treenode

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have TreeView like as below
[image]

I want to get text of treeNode: `Day` `Month` `Year`: like picture
[image]

then I code

```
public List<myData> getData(TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        List<myData> lsData = new List<myData>();

        foreach (TreeNode item in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            if (item.Nodes.Count != 0)
            {
                getData(item);
            }

            if (item.Level == 3)
            {

                myData objData = new myData();
                objData.myDay = int.Parse(item.Text);

                string myMonth = item.Parent.Text;
                objData.myMonth = int.Parse(myMonth);

                string myYear = item.Parent.Parent.Text;
                objData.myYear = int.Parse(myYear);

                lsData.Add(objData);
            }
        }
        return lsData;
    }
```

class `myData` is:

```
public class myData
{
    public int myYear { get; set; }
    public int myMonth { get; set; }
    public int myDay { get; set; }
}
```

But when it return is null
I dont know why.
Pls give me your advise

Comment: use a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes. I did, but when second turn, debugger run into `return lsData` => it make data of `lsData` is become null => function return null.

Comment: ah... you should have `lsData.AddRange(getData(item));` in the recursive part. otherwise recursed subtrees won't ever be added back to the calling scope's `lsData` instance.

Comment: Oh, thanks. My problem has been solved